# Python: Static class attribute of the class itself

Tags: python

I recently made a class. Let's say that the class is declared as below.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, modifiers):
        ....
```

The problem is, I want to create constant instances of the class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, modifiers):
        ....

    CONSTANT_MEMBER_1 = MyClass(my_modifiers)
    CONSTANT_MEMBER_2 = MyClass(my_modifiers)
```

Unfortunately, Python won't allow me to do so, with error:

```
E    NameError: global name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Any solution for this problem?

One alternative would be creating a 'static' method for the class that will return a same object each time it's called (e.g., `MyClass.CONSTANT_MEMBER_1()`). But I think I would still prefer to access it using `MyClass.CONSTANT_MEMBER_1`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a little more? A "static attribute or method" has a specific meaning here, but you seem to be using "static member" to refer to: "an instance of the class that never changes"

Comment: @brianpck yes, I meant to refer to "constant instances of the class". Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to class variables right after the class has been defined.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, modifiers):
        ....

MyClass.CONSTANT_MEMBER_1 = MyClass(my_modifiers)
MyClass.CONSTANT_MEMBER_2 = MyClass(my_modifiers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe make use of inheritance and [custom descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), [Python Descriptors Demystified](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb)

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'I am {}'.format(self.color)

class Foo(MyClass):
    ConstantMember_blue = MyClass('blue')
    ConstantMember_red = MyClass('red')

f = Foo('green')

>>> f
I am green
>>> f.ConstantMember_blue
I am blue
>>> f.ConstantMember_red
I am red
>>> Foo.ConstantMember_blue
I am blue
>>> Foo.ConstantMember_red
I am red
>>>
```